# How do I get a Title for my tibble after using group by and summarize?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have to calculate the mean of two variables grouped by month but when Im seeing the output in R markdown there is no title or heading on top so one cannot tell by looking at the tibble which variable its showing me averages for !

Is there some package / function that i can use to create a title header for my tibble ?

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid asking questions without context. You should post a question with enough details. See the link I have posted on another of your questions.

Comment: i dont understand how context is missing . Please see user reply to both my threads. they have understood my requirements and addressed my concerns. sorry if i havent met your standards for posting reproducible examples if thats what youre after, im fairly new here and learning about R and SO everyday

Comment: Answering a question is not simply about understanding what  the poster wants. It's meant to help future users(me, you and everyone). Questions without enough detail are not very useful. Read the link I posted on your question for more details on what makes a good SO question.

Comment: ok mate , thanks for your message , ill have a look ! cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at the RMarkdown [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf)

Let's say your `tibble` is called `data`, you can do:

```
knitr::kable(data, caption = "My data")
```